# Eclipse not deploying 'Web Content' to root folder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment

I have following in my workspace :

[image]

and below on configured as deployment assembly :

[image]

Still I dont see everything deployed to :

`\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\<workspace>`

[image]

What could be going wrong ?

Comment: How did the Web Content folder get in the workspace? Import through file system or SVN checkout?

Comment: Its part of standard web dir structure for dynamic web project that eclipse creates.

Comment: Why do you need to change the directory structure if it has been dynamically created by Eclipse?

Comment: I didnt change the structure...

Comment: I misunderstood. Hmm, your problem indeed is weird.

Comment: Your first screenshot, the one that shows folder structure, can you update that to show the full folder structure? Use Paint or Gimp to darken any specific names if you need to. Without seeing the complete structure it's hard to guess if you're even looking in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything. I guess your workspace is corrupted, just try with brand new one, it should solve the deployment issue!